# Unable to Update Person Account records with AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have Person Accounts synced with MC from SF CRM, the Person Account record Id's are marked as Subscriber Key and they all starts with "003".
Now, I need to update those person accounts in Salesforce using AMPscript through Cloud Page, the email sends record Id to cloud page and AMP script tries to update the record in SF based on the same Id.
Problem here is, AMP cant find this record since the Id starts with "003" (where actual Account Id starts with 001).

Is there any way to update those Person Accounts using Id which starts with "003" ?

Answer (score 0):

the id starts with "003" means it's a contact Id for the personal account as salesforce create an account("001") and contact("003").

so If you want to get the accounted from Contact try this

```
contact.accountId
```

Comment: This wont work. Such type of traversing works well in APEX/SOQL but when we define Object name to pull records from, neither AMP or Apex can identify the name with "." notations.

Error:  "Salesforce.com Fault thrown.\n\tException Type:InvalidSObjectFault\n\tException Code:INVALID_TYPE\n\tException Message:sObject type 'Contact.AccountId' is not supported."